# What does the symbol on Amon's banners mean?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra, avatar-the-last-airbender

In episode 6 of The Legend of Korra, "Korra Gets Cheated," Amon attacks the Pro Bending Championship.

Midway through his attack, his followers hang banners with his symbol throughout the arena.

[image: Amon with banners in the background]

What does the symbol stand for?

I noticed it looks symmetrical. Is it a Chinese symbol for equal or equality?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The character is 平 píng. It means equal, flat, or level. It can also mean calm or peaceful.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is used in both Japanese and Chinese, and it can be used a both a verb, an adverb, and an adjective. It means level/flat ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.dk/#auto/en/%E5%B9%B3)).

[image: Google Translate screenshot]

Comment: I edited in the Google Translate screenshot because it is helpful to show all the meanings. Usually the text would be better but in this case I think a screenshot works well.